# How to import an Enum

Tags: typescript

I have created an enum, but I am having trouble importing and using the enum in VS15.

This is the enum which is contained in enums.ts:

```
enum EntityStatus {
     New = 0,
     Active = 1,
     Archived = 2,
     Trashed = 3,
     Deleted = 4
}
```

Visual Studio sees this enum without even importing and so does not give a compile time error.  But at runtime, an error is thrown

```
 Cannot read property 'Archived' of undefined.
```

So now I try to import it like I import other classes:

```
 import {EntityStatus} from "../../core/enums";
```

Visual Studio now gives a compile time error:

```
 "...enums is not a module ..."
```

So how do I import the enum?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I was missing the export keyword:

```
 export enum EntityStatus {
      New = 0,
      Active = 1,
      Archived = 2,
      Trashed = 3,
      Deleted = 4
 }
```

Then it worked as expected. (But see @Martin Braun's comment below)

Comment: Be sure to have this within a `*.ts`. 
`*.d.ts` files will not work. A pitfall I ran into.

Comment: But how can I find the corresponding **real** type definition? Visual Studio code directs me only to the *.d.ts file. How can i now where the "real" enum is defined? Then i can import the file.

Comment: @MartinBraun YOU ARE A LIFESAVER

Answer (score 44):

You will get the same `Cannot read property 'Foo' of undefined.` runtime error when you happen to define your Enum in one of the TypeScript Declaration files (`*.d.ts`) as these files does not get transpiled into JavaScript.

More details with a sample app can be found [here](http://lukasbehal.com/2017-05-22-enums-in-declaration-files).

Comment: I don't think a *.d.ts would be a good place to define an Enum.

Comment: Well, me neither. Especially after the time wasted by figuring out why my enum is not defined :)

Comment: You can then just use an object to export the code in a separate .js file eg: export const EReviewStatus = {
  PENDING: 'PENDING',
  SENT: 'SENT'
}

Comment: This is a major pain. I'm using global TS importing and TS can't see the exported enum that I have put in a different file for this very reason. This means that none of my type declarations are able to reference an enum unless I duplicate the enum in the .d.ts file.

Has anyone found another way?

Answer (score 29):

Kindly try this. It works for me

enums.ts

```
export enum  Category {Cricket,Tennis,Golf,Badminton}
```

and in required .ts file import like the way given below:

```
import {Category} from './enums'
```

Answer (score 23):

Just ran across something similar. In my case, I had to ensure the exported enum name was different than the name of the file.

ie.

export enum AccessMode in file access-mode.ts would fail.
export enum AccessMode in file access-modes.ts would work.

Comment: surprisingly it worked for me as well. Do you know the reason for this, why this is happening?

Comment: This answer helped me "fix" an issue with Rollup where it would not export my enum.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sachin Kalia said, I had a problem with imports.

I have changed this:

```
import {MessageAction, MessageDTO} from '../../../generated/dto';
```

to this:

```
import {MessageDTO} from '../../../generated/dto';
import {MessageAction} from '../../../generated/dto'
```

MessageAction is my enum.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you just need to **restart the dev server** if the grammar is ok.

In my case, I've already defined the `export enum ...`. But the log console still warns me "...has no exported member...", it seems like `enum` type has a different import mechanism.
But after I restarted the dev server, the errors had gone.

Answer (score -6):

Encountered similar issue. For me removing the name Enum worked.

**Before :**

> ```
> export enum ContentStatusEnum
> {
>     New = 0,
>     Saved = 1,
>     Ready = 2,
>     Sent = 3,
>     Cancel = 4,
>     OnError = 5
> }
> ```

**After:**

> ```
> export enum ContentStatus
> {
>     New = 0,
>     Saved = 1,
>     Ready = 2,
>     Sent = 3,
>     Cancel = 4,
>     OnError = 5
> }
> ```

Comment: This was exacly my issue thank you