# How to import enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, enums

I have the following two files: bag.js

```
import {BagType} from "./bagType"     //this line of code gives an error message: bagtype.ts is not a modul
import {Present} from "./present";

export class Bag {

    private maxWeight: number;
    private bagType: BagType;
    private presents: Array<Present> = new Array<Present>();

    constructor(maxWeight: number, bagType: BagType) {
        this.maxWeight = maxWeight;
        this.bagType = bagType;
    }

    public addPresent(present: Present){
        this.presents.push(present);
    }
}
```

and bagType.js

```
enum BagType {

    Canvas,
    Paper
}
```

My question is the next: How can I import the enum BagType to the Bag class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553097/how-to-import-an-enum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it and it worked with:

```
export enum BagType{
    Canvas,
    Paper
}
```

and

```
import {BagType} from "./bagType";
```

Comment: I forgot the export tag from the beginning. Thanks.