# TypeScript: Enum object is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am creating an application by TypeScript and using WebPack to transpile and bundle.
I am using the final result of this application in a pure JavaScript website. In this application I have defined an enum as below:

```
export const enum ShapeType {
    Actor,Ellipse,Border,Connector
}
```

I also exported it as:

```
export { ShapeType } from "./shape/shape.type";
```

But when I try to use it like:

```
 var createdShape = new shapeFactory.createShape(ShapeType.Ellipse);
```

It does not create a shape and when I debug I see this error:**"ShapeType is not defined"**
I also try to find ShapeType in the final JavaScript bundle file, but I found out there is no ShapeType in the bundle file too.
I don't have a problem when I import it inside TS.

The code below is the js code. ChartDraw is the library name I defined in my webpack config file. All other functions work fine. The only problem is with

```
var aa = shapeFactory.createShape(ChartDraw.ShapeType.Ellipse);
```

because ShapeType is not defined.

```
   var svg = new ChartDraw.Svg("drawing");
    var shapeFactory = new ChartDraw.ShapeFactory(svg);
    var ob1 = null;
    var ob2 = null;
    //aa.draw();
    var cc = new ChartDraw.Connector(svg);
    var bb = new ChartDraw.MouseReader();
    bb.setExportFunction(info => {
        var aa = shapeFactory.createShape(ChartDraw.ShapeType.Ellipse);
        aa.rectangularPosition = info;
        aa.draw();
        if (ob1 == null)
            ob1 = aa;
        else {
            ob2 = info;
            cc.beginObject = ob1;
            cc.endObject = aa;
            cc.draw();
        }
    });
```

And the code below is where I import ShapeType:

```
import { ShapeType } from "./shape.type";
import { Actor } from "./actor";
import { Svg } from "../svg";
import { Shape } from "./shape";
import { Ellipse } from "./ellipse";

export class ShapeFactory {
    private svg: Svg;
    constructor(svg: Svg) {
        this.svg = svg;
    }
    public createShape(shape: ShapeType):Shape {
        switch (shape) {
            case ShapeType.Actor:
                let actor = new Actor(this.svg);
                return actor;
            case ShapeType.Ellipse:
                let ell = new Ellipse(this.svg);
                return ell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553097/how-to-import-an-enum)

Comment: Not really, it is a different story. I have this issue when I convert it to JS. When I import it in another TS file it works fine.

Comment: I guess you didn't import ShapeType. You need perhaps import {ShapeType} from 'pathOfJSFile';

Comment: Can you share your JS file ? If the issue is with JS and not TS. That will help in quick debug.

Comment: Surely this line export { ShapeType } from "./shape/shape.type"; should be import { ShapeType } from "./shape/shape.type";

Comment: @Andrew, No Andrew, I have import inside the ShapeFactory file. The export is inside index.ts to make sure it is accessible inside an external js file.

Comment: I don't think you need to export it twice given this code. Can you also share how you're importing it in the other file?

Comment: @apokryfos Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found out what is the problem.
The first problem was because of the const. When typescript code is converting to JavaScript, an enum converts to an object, but if I add the const keyword it is not an object anymore. So to fix it I removed the const as below:

```
export enum ShapeType {
    Actor,Ellipse,Border,Connector
}
```

The second issue was in my JavaScript code. At first step, I forgot to add library name(ChartDraw) to the ShapeType when calling `shapeFactory.createShape(ChartDraw.ShapeType.Ellipse)`